# New Badge Proposal: Top x %

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badge-request

what is your opinion about having a bage

- **Top x %**

which is based on reputation earnings during a certain time period?
note: this info is displayed on the user summary page tab.

the idea is to gain the badges multiple times (if you qualify) after the time period (e.g.: month,quarter,year) and keep them.

You can come up with numbers for **x** regarding bronze, silver, gold status and the time periods (month,quarter,year).

Motivating users to get them would also boost participation.

**note:** you can express your approval/disapproval by up-/down-vote and/or answering directly your likes or dislikes.

Comment: And what happens when a user falls out of the top x%? Stack Overflow does not like removing awarded badges.

Comment: you gain them after the period (month,quarter,year) and keep them.

Comment: Please clarify if this badge (or badges, if one adds bronze/silver/gold variants) could be awarded multiple times.

Comment: @lockstep: added it to the question. thanks.

Comment: I like the idea of making the ephemeral a bit more concrete... well, as concrete as a badge is.

Answer (score 13):

I suspect we'd have mostly the same users collecting loads of these, but here's one recommendation:

- Bronze: In the top ten of the reputation leagues at the end of a [week](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=week).
- Silver: In the top ten of the reputation leagues at the end of a [month](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=month).
- Gold: In the top ten of the reputation leagues at the end of a [year](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=year).

Make the badges stackable so that you don't have to revoke them.  (If you get a bronze reputation league badge it shows that you were one of the top contributors of the week at some point in the past.)

Comment: exactly. this is how I thought it could work. maybe to be carful with the weekly badges to avoid badge "inflation"...

Comment: @udo I was going to shift the first two up to monthly and quarterly, but then you'd really have the same group of people getting all of these badges.  With the bronze badge being for the weekly league, then really anybody could have a chance at it.

Comment: agreed. another possibility is to base the "material" on a certain %-age/period combination, e.g.: bronze -> 10%, silver -> 5%, gold -> 1% or some numbers that make more sense.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "stackable". Would the badges be awarded multiple times or just once? (Would Jon Skeet have 39 of those silver badges if implemented retro-actively, or just one?)

Comment: @Mat Yes, by "stackable" I mean that the badge can be awarded multiple times.

Comment: @Mat: if the criteria of earning those badges would qualify him for 39 times, he would have 39 badges. it would be important to have criteria where also non-superusers have a chance to gain them (with putting some effort in the action of course).

Comment: Top ten users (not percent)?  Isn't that a bit tough for a bronze badge?

Comment: @KeithThompson Ten percent would make it way too easy.  Top 50 maybe?  I think we'd want to make it attainable but not too easy.

Comment: A quick skim of the weekly rankings suggests that Top 25 is probably equivalent to "hit the rep cap every day that week". Hitting Top 10 requires substantially more than 200 rep per day. There's merit to the latter--someone like Jon Skeet can hit the rep cap from votes on older questions without even visiting the site, but exceeding it requires participation.

Comment: @McCannot Great point.  I definitely think we'd want to try and balance the requirements so that the bronze badge isn't *too* difficult, but it should require some participation and effort.

Answer (score 3):

Are we sure we want to encourage people to hit the rep cap every single day? Isn't the cap there to give people some time to sleep as well? :-)

Another problem is that this looks like a badge-badge, as these badges will go to people who already earn tons of badges. If you earn 1500-2000 rep a week, you already get a couple of Nice answer, Good question, and possibly Enlightened as well. Some of them even come in pairs, like Enlightened+Nice answer.

Isn't that enough?

Comment: Sleep is for the weak. I don't think I earn that many points a week--I've had pretty good weeks, but rarely get badges for it because I mostly participate in poorly-traveled tags. The badge isn't precisely for hitting the rep cap anyway, it's for being among the top answerers over a timespan. That may often imply topping out, but that's a side-effect.

Comment: @Dave - The problem is that the top-of-the-top actually reaches 300-500 points a day. Hit rep cap for upvotes *plus* 20 accepted answers every day! And add a bounty or two...

Comment: Top scorer this week is at 833 points, and it is only Monday! http://stackoverflow.com/users

Comment: So? The top ten don't generally do as well, like me.